# How to encrypt in a client side (Android) and decrypt in a server side (PHP) with "Tink"

Tags: php, android, tink

I have used this [demo](https://github.com/google/tink/tree/master/examples/helloworld/android) for the Android side.

In my case, I want to set this encrypt and decrypt process in the REST API. if someone has API through the reverse process(decompile) of Apk and call this API anyhow so I want to secure this process through this Tink.